# Claim anonymous question from SharePoint Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, questions

I asked [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10729/redirecting-search-results) on SharePoint Overflow shortly before the move to SE2.0. Is there any way I can "reclaim" it?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "reclaim"?

Comment: I think he is asking whether he canb add that question to his profile(?)

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged this user:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2809/dan

To your registered account:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2957/rawling

You should be good to go!

Comment: Cheers, that's done it :)